# How are Chaos;Head, Steins;Gate, and Robotics;Notes connected?

Tags: steins-gate, robotics-notes, chaos-head

These series all *seem* to be connected, but asides from sharing the same production company and having the semi-colon separate their titles I can't see any relation between them. The plots seem to be completely disjoint.

[image: best girls?]

When I was looking up Chaos;Head and Stein's;Gate, I also found Robotics;Notes, but it too seems to not be connected. Can anyone explain the connection between these series for me?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

*Chaos;Head* and *Steins;Gate* exist in the same ("Science Adventure") universe, but on different world lines.

- *Chaos;Head* happens in [Shibuya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibuya) and the events happen one year before *Steins;Gate*
- *Steins;Gate* happens in [Akihabara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akihabara)
- *Robotic;Notes* happens in [Tanegashima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanegashima) Island and the events happen nine years after *Steins;Gate*

The events of *Chaos;Head* are consistent with the events of *Steins;Gate* within the Beta worldline, divergence ratio: 1.130426%. *Steins;Gate* and *Robotics;Note* exist on the "Steins;Gate" worldline, divergence ratio: 1.048596%. (*Steins;Gate* was also originally in the same worldline as *Chaos;Head*, which changed after Okabe sent the first D-Mail and passed to another worldline.)

There is a mention of "Knight Hart" which is the online persona of *Chaos;Head*'s protagonist Nishijou Takumi, in episode 4 of *Steins;Gate*. In the *Steins;Gate* game, it's [mentioned that this character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRHYi.jpg) was also looking for the IBN 5100 (the non-conical 8-bit version of the game gets more in depth into his motvations).

Kurisu explained the "Time Leap Machine" concept to Okabe using NOZOMI papers from *Chaos;Head*.

On big TV outdoors, FES's performance can be seen in the Alpha timeline. Giving the right reply to Faris's mail earns the player Ayase's portrait and FES's music, sung by Kanako Itou, which include the *Chaos;Head* OP, "Find the Blue."

There's a Seira-tan cosplay cameo in *Steins;Gate* as well:

[image: Kururururururrururururururusu-tina!]

*Robotics;Note* connects the two series a bit more by revealing that the "Committee of 300" are the driving force between the major events of all three series.

> [image: "Committee of 300" Relationship chart]

Nae from *Steins;Gate* appears as an adult in *Robotics;Note*. Daru and Kurisu show up on the Twipo network in *Robotics;Note* as "DaSH". In the VN game, Kurisu [uses a tripcode](https://web.archive.org/web/20150321204741/http://ibm5100.net/steinswiki/2011/09/09/heroine-qgate/). In the anime, Kurisu posts in @channel under the handle "[KURI_KAME](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_Glossary#Term_2:_KuriGohan_and_Kamehameha)" in episode 15 (about 2D and 3D limitations).

> Daru writes the program that eradicates Kimijima Kou from Iru-o.

SERN (and their projects) is also mentioned several times in both *Steins;Gate* and *Robotics;Note*

Comment: Does the more recent Occultic;Nine relate to the three too? If so, how?

Answer (score 16):

Steins;Gate, Chaos;Head, and Robotics;Notes all take place within the same universe but at different times.

There are  also multiple Steins;Gate references in Chaos;Head, and there are multiple Steins;Gate references in Robotics;Notes.

These could be just for comedy purposes or they could be hinting at a relationship. Robotics;Notes also takes place in the Steins;Gate Divergence Ratio 1.048596.

Other than that the Visual Novels of all three were created by 5pd and Nitroplus.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "Whose eyes are those eyes?" appears in both Robotics;Notes and Chaos;Head. In the first episode of Robotics;Notes you can hear Airi say it. It's the same phrase Nishijo Takumi repeats almost every episode in Chaos;Head, because he feels like someone is observing him. It's also one of Kishimoto Ayase's songs in Chaos;Head.