# Chaos;Head, Steins;Gate, Robotics;Notes: where is all the extra information?

Tags: steins-gate, robotics-notes, chaos-head

To make it short:
I watched all three anime adaptations, but after browsing the questions here for 5 minutes I feel like I don't know anything about them...

<strike>Where is all this extra information hidden?</strike>

(More specific question:)
I am searching for information about 2 things.

1. "Hidden" information which is only for one story.
2. "Hidden" information which is cross-story (at least two stories "combined")

Now I'll specify what I mean with that.

1. (This example is not related to the stories in the title.) For example, something like the real name of L (from Death Note).
2. Something like "What is DaSH?"

I do NOT want you to list all the secrets and easter-eggs! I only want to know where, and (maybe) how to find them. If there are manga with extra information, please give me the title. Or if there are articles on the internet about it, please give me a link.

(I know that there are visual novels for all the stories listed in the title. I'm going to watch/read/play them soon.)

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are asking. General, open-ended question are [bad](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: All three of these stories were originally visual novels before they were animated. The visual novels are significantly longer and contain a lot more information than was shown in the corresponding anime. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @senshin Okay, so the VNs contain everything not shown in the Anime?

Comment: @user15266 For the most part. There are also some other spinoffs (at least, I know that Steins;Gate has something like half a dozen manga / light novel sidestories), but the bulk of the information that isn't in the anime is in the visual novels.

Comment: Reopening the question since OP has clarified what s/he's looking for. Related question (which I know OP has already seen; just adding for completeness): http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4354/

Comment: @senshin I disagree. I believe the scope is too broad and border on gameplay if it includes the games in it's scope. Please try to make an active effort to be in chat to discuss this.

Comment: As your question is right now, it is too broad because there's too much detail to cover all at once. Please consider breaking it down into three question about each particular series. Use the visual novels as you primary source of reference as it is the most canonical and authoritative source.

Answer (score 0):

As said by senshin in [his](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22737/chaoshead-steinsgate-roboticsnotes-where-is-all-the-extra-information#comment32482_22737) [comments](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22737/chaoshead-steinsgate-roboticsnotes-where-is-all-the-extra-information#comment32484_22737) the Chaos;Head, Steins;Gate and Robotic;Notes anime series are adaptions of Visual Novels. bellow is a list of the corresponding games on VNDB (Visual Novel Database)

- [Chaos;Head](https://vndb.org/v382)
- [Steins;Gate](https://vndb.org/v2002)
- [Robotic;Notes](https://vndb.org/v5883)

From each of those links you can also find links to the anime and other games based off each of these. however not all of these one would consider canon and most times these would have [Unofficial] in their title or have Fan-Fiction as a tag, ie. [Steins;gate Divergence](https://vndb.org/v15695). As senshin has said

> The visual novels are significantly longer and contain a lot more information than was shown in the corresponding anime

This obviously because of time constraints on Anime being set to go on for a set number of episodes of certain length (normally between ~12 and ~24 episodes ~20 minutes long Excluding OP and ED). multiple seasons of a series are normally either done based on popularity of the previous season or planned because it is foretasted that the previous season will sell well (as with Fate/Zero and Fate/Stay Night: Unlimited Blade Works).

Another source of information is also Art/Material Books such as the [Steins;Gate Official Material Collection Book](http://www.animebooks.com/stofmacobo.html). these tend to have a bit more information that may not have originally been in the Visual Novels. in my experience large series tend to have these to fill in some plot holes, for instance in the Nasuverse (Fate/Stay Night, Tsukihime etc.) the Material Books go into depth about the 27 Dead Apostle Ancestors, the on-goings between the Church and the Mage's Association and the Aylesbury Valesti which is theorized to have been the cause of the Prana drying up in the world in Fate/Extra.

Also on occasion at conventions some writers/developers hold Q&A Sessions where fans can ask them a number of questions. these can sometimes also been included in Material Books.

However most of the time this extra information is in Japanese, for English fans who don't know Japanese this can be a barrier when the work isn't translated. for instance while Chaos;Head and Steins;Gate have English translations, both fan made and official, Robotic;Notes does not and the likely hood of a fan translation of it is very unlikely due to the game being on Console.

in these situations a Wiki (normally a Wikia site) tends to be a good source of information. however one need to be careful as sometimes there are [two](http://chaoshead2.wikia.com/wiki/Rimi_Sakihata) [Wikias](http://chaos-head.wikia.com/wiki/Rimi_Sakihata) for one game however one can normally tell which is of inferior quality. also despite the 3 titles mentioned being apart of the ***The Science Adventure series*** (科学ＡＤＶ, *Kagaku Adobenchaa*) there is [three](http://chaoshead2.wikia.com/wiki/Science_Adventure_Series) [separate](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Science_Adventure_Series) [wikias](http://robotics-notes.wikia.com/wiki/Science_Adventure_Series). sometimes however you may get lucky with a series which has a single wiki (eg. [Type-Moon](http://typemoon.wikia.com/)<sup>1</sup>, [Final Fantasy](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/)<sup>2</sup>)

Ofcause one should take heed with Wikia's as these tend to not normally be maintained by the developers. a good sign that a Wikia is reliable is what kind of References it has, on the Type-Moon Wikia information gained from Q&A sessions will be included most of the time in both Japanese and in English

---

<sup>1: Titles include Fate/Stay Night, Tsukihime, Kagetsu Tohya, Melty Blood, Kara no Kyoukai, Notes, etc.</sup>

<sup>2: Titles include the Final Fantasy games (I - XV, Tactics, Crystal Chronicles), Vagrant Story, Bravery Default, The Four Heroes of Light, etc.</sup>